# need python subprocess to keep the http req opened but not block other http reqs

Tags: python, request, subprocess, blocking

I need to call a python service (I am using bottle and gunicorn) which runs a dd command (http req 1), and also I need to be able to terminate the process at any time with another call (http req 2).

A) IF I do something like:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.stdout.read().strip()
```

The http req 2 waits until http req 1 ends (so reading the output is blocking concurrent calls)

B) IF I write the output to a file, http req 1 does not block other requests, but this request ends meanwhile the command is being executed in the background.

So, what I need is to keep alive http req 1 until the command finishes, but at the same time I need to be able to terminate the process with another request. (If I use a simple time.sleep(x) instead of reading the output I get what I want, the req 1 keeps alive, and I can call req 2 at the same time)

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout + `select.select([p.stdout.fileno()], [], [], timeout)`, but the simpliest way is to use
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll to check that process terminated and read output only when subprocess terminated.

```
while p.pool() is None: # supprocess alive
    time.sleep(timeout)
out = p.stdout.read()
```